# cloud-init "x-shellscript-per-boot" does not trigger on reboot

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, cloud-init

I am using terraform to configure cloud-init. I used "x-shellscript-per-boot" to trigger my script on every reboot, but it does not work. It triggers only once when the instance is created.

```
data "cloudinit_config" "provision" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = true

  # Creates a script on the server at a particular location
  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = local.cloud_config_config
  }
  /*
  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename     = "example.sh"
    content  = <<-EOT
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World"
      /opt/userdata/userdata.sh
    EOT
   }
   */

  // This does NOT work. As per the documentation, this script should trigger on reboot.
  part {
    content_type = "x-shellscript-per-boot"
    filename     = "example.sh"
    content  = <<-EOT
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World"
      /opt/userdata/userdata.sh
    EOT
  }

}
```